# Bounds on the number of samples needed to learn a real valued function class

Tags: st.statistics, discrete-geometry, learning-theory

Let us see Theorem 6.8 in this book, [https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)

It gives us a lowerbound (and also an upperbound) on the number of samples needed to learn a 0/1 valued hypothesis class of finite VC

Such a Theorem 6.8 for real valued functions is not known to me!

- I am wondering why something like fat-shattering dimension not give such bounds (particularly the lowerbound) for real valued classes. So far I cant spot any such result in literature. Is there a known bottleneck to this?

Comment: This stuff has definitely been studied and is in the literature. Maybe ask on cstheory stack exchange if noone here gives a reference.

Comment: I feel if this is studied then this is in some quite obscure literature!

Answer (score 2):

Theorem 19.5 in *Anthony, Martin; Bartlett, Peter L.*, [**Neural network learning: Theoretical foundations**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511624216) (1999). gives the lower bound. The agnostic sample complexity of learning a real-valued function class $F \subseteq [0,1]^{X}$ up to error $\epsilon$ is roughly $\Omega(\text{fat}_{4 \epsilon}(F))$. Anthony and Bartlett's lower bound is for quadratic loss, and their proof is based on a reduction to binary classification.

Sridharan provides a lower bound on the minimax value of regression with respect to absolute loss on [these](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6783/2015fa/lec12.pdf) notes.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are such results.

- Yes, fat-shattering dimension and pseudo-dimension are used to characterize sample complexity. For example, [here are some lecture notes (pdf)](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eethanf/teaching/ItSLT_16/lectures/lec_fat_no_anim.pdf) I found with a quick internet search.
- For another thing, Rademacher complexity is defined for real-valued functions and characterizes sample complexity of learning. See Chapter 26 of that book, or other books like Foundations of Machine Learning.
- In general I think there are several things you could mean by "for real-valued functions". For example, you could be thinking of regression where a hypothesis is of the form $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ and a label is of the form $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the loss is $\ell(h(x),y) := (h(x) - y)^2$. This would generally need a different set of tools, at least because the loss is unbounded.

Comment: Hi. I know these references. I don't think these answer my full question. (a) the proofs in those slides do not enable me - as far as I can see - to get a sample complexity lowerbound for the case of real valued functions - they can only give upperbounds on the generalization error in terms of the covering number in general and in terms of fat-shattering-dimension only for the restrictive $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ class. (b) Rademacher complexity is a distribution dependent bound and hence that is by definition something much weaker a starting point if one is aiming to match this Theorem 6.8

Comment: @Student I think it would help if you state precisely what statement you want to prove.

Comment: @usul I'm curious. Is there a (text)book reference you know of for this stuff.

Comment: @mathworker21 The textbook that I referred to is pretty much all that there is.

Comment: @usul You can see what Theorem 6.8 in that referred book is achieving :  it is giving a lowerbound on the number of samples for achieving agnostic PAC learning for 0/1 valued functions. One of the key things that I am looking for is if an analogue of this is known for real valued functions.

Comment: @Student the real valued functions part is what I suggest you formalize since I'm not sure what you mean and maybe others don't either.

Comment: @mathworker21 there is also Foundations of Machine Learning https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/ and probably a bunch of less well known ones, but I would also search for good lecture notes.

Comment: @usul Just consider a hypothesis class whose neither the domain nor the range is a discrete space. The lecture notes that you have attached already use this terminology of real valued functions for its hypothesis class. Where is the confusion here?

Comment: The confusion is discussed my third bullet point. A learning problem needs not just a hypothesis class but also a loss function. I mention how certain settings have answers, then Student replies that they are aware of those settings and not interested in them, so the question is what settings they are interested in.